# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.deploy.config.WinPlatform.getPlatformUserHome()Ljava/lang/String

Tags: java, javafx

I developed a javafx(2.2) application that link to a certain site. The app is running fine in netbeans 7.3 but when I deploy it the following error will occur.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.deploy.config.WinPlatform.getPlatformUserHome()Ljava/lang/String;
    at com.sun.deploy.config.WinPlatform.getPlatformUserHome(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.config.WinPlatform.getUserHome(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.config.WinPlatform.getLocalStorageDir(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.config.Config.getLocalStorageDir(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.config.Config.getDefaultCacheDirectory(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.config.DefaultConfig.init(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.config.DefaultConfig.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.config.DefaultConfig.getDefaultConfig(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.config.Config.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.UserDefinedProxyConfig.getBrowserProxyInfo(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.DynamicProxyManager.reset(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.DeployProxySelector.reset(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.javafx.main.Main.tryToSetProxy(Main.java:572)
    at com.javafx.main.Main.launchApp(Main.java:640)
    at com.javafx.main.Main.main(Main.java:805)
```

I really don't know what is the cause of the problem. Is it my proxy or platform I used? I am using java 1.7 32bit Hope someone will help me. Thanks.

Comment: did you find a solution? i've got exactly the same problem!

Comment: I am still working on this problem..

Comment: now, from me this error too. I'm create in NB 7.3 win xp 32bit OS and where I starting .jar on windows server 64x, I see this error =(

Comment: I found the answer. I use not 64x lib in lib dir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved compiling the code on a 32bit pc with only 32bit jdk installed. It worked for me cause I have a 32bit application (once compiled it works fine on 64bit pc as well) but i guess that if you need a 64bit application compile it on 64bit pc with the 64bit jdk and netbeans configured for working with this jdk.

Comment: I am using 32bit pc with 32bit jdk installed already, it works well in IDE Netbeans 7.3 but when I build to create a jar file..the problem occurred.

Comment: try creating a new default project (javafx application) compile it and try executing the jar. See whether it works or it gives you back the error and let me know.

Comment: Yes, I did that already where in fact the problem first show up when I tried to run it in Netbean IDE, then I decided to create a new javafx project then copy all the classes and compile it, the problem is fixed but when I tried to build it and run the jar executable the error occurs.

Comment: yes but i meant you should create a new default "Hello World" javafx project and try to run this one (after compiling) from the jar. That actually should work...and if so, you should check differences in project properties between your project and the new one.

Comment: It seems like you advice help me to solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: If the solution here didn't actually solve the problem, can you please update it with whatever did solve the problem?  As it is now, it's not very helpful to others.